# error on "addBasicPlayerListener(this)"

Tags: java, audio, netbeans

I'm working with javazoom and basicplayer libraries, and I'm trying to register BasicPlayerListener events.

I'm following this > [guide](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer) <
but when I write the line> `player.addBasicPlayerListener(this);`

Netbeans says that I need to cast the variable like this: `player.addBasicPlayerListener((BasicPlayerListener) this);`

but when I run the proyect throw this exception>

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   listentoguether.Reproductor cannot be cast to
>   javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayerListener

pardon my English

Comment: You must use a class that implements `BasicPlayerListener` for the listener

Answer (score 0):

There are just too many possible causes of the exception. I had a look of the guide and the code `player.addBasicPlayerListener(this);` appears in 4 places.

Without further details of the exception and exact place where the error was thrown, my best guess is the class `listentoguether.Reproductor` should implement the interface `BasicPlayerListener`.